# To what extent did Defoe attempt to apply formal realism in Robinson Crusoe?

Tags: history-of-literature, realism, daniel-defoe, robinson-crusoe

I recently finished writing a paper on *Robinson Crusoe* for my English class on the rise of the novel. We had read the novel concurrently with excerpts from Ian Watt's *The Rise of the Novel*, in which he argued that the works of Defoe, Richardson (we then read *Pamela*) and Fielding - which Watt categorized as the early novels - used what he called ["formal realism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_realism#United_Kingdom). Moreover, he stated that these were some of the first - if not *the* first - significant pieces of literature to do so.

*Robinson Crusoe* bears many hallmarks of formal realism (as I understand them):

- The presentation of people and events as "evidence", to use Watt's phrasing.
- An attention to detail even in cases where it might seem overboard. For instance, some sections of Crusoe's journal seem . . . unnecessary. At the least, as we discussed, it's not clear that they're intended to advance the plot.
- The implication that this is an authentic presentation of the events as they occurred.

All of this has me a little curious as to the thought processes of Defoe and company (although I'll stick to Defoe, for simplicity). Was Defoe aware that he was using a new sort of realist techniques, and was this usage intentional? Put another way, are the indicators of formal realism in *Robinson Crusoe* part of an effort by Defoe, or just elements of the writing that were noticed long after the fact?