# Bakhtin quote about flat plots and characters

Tags: quote-source, mikhail-bakhtin

Through serendipity ([this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3929/2191) led me to [Wikipedia article about Ian Watt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Watt)) I found that that the Russian literary theorist Mikhael Bakhtin is supposed to have written that certain genres with flat plots and characters

> can literally be read front to back, or back to front, with no significant difference in effect.

Note that the wording is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Watt#Literary_criticism) (or from Ian Watt?): it is not in quotation marks and no source is given. The Wikipedia article about [Mikhail Bakhtin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Bakhtin) does not mention this statement. So which of Bakhtin's publications is the source of this statement?